# Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function Error in single values

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a query like

```
update sports
set firstname= LEFT(Contact_name, LEN(Contact_name) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Contact_name))) 
,lastname=  STUFF(RIGHT(Contact_name, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Contact_name))),1,1,'')
```

Now there is a value in contact where there is only 1 value or blank
like

```
contact_name
christopher

prof any virk

expected result:
firstname
christopher

prof any
```

it is working fine for multiple values but
it is giving error at single values or blank, let me know how can i include the single value in same sql statement

I can overcome it with "WHERE CHARINDEX(' ', Contact_name) >1 " but then it is excluding the cells with single name.

let me know how can i add an condition for single name in same sql statement

Comment: So, when `CHARINDEX` returns `0`, what are you after? Sample data and expected results will help us help you. Either `NULLIF` or a `WHERE` is going to be what you're after, that that depends on what it is you want.

Comment: Also what do you do for `Mario von Peebles` or `Christian van der Kirk` or `James Earl Jones` or `Earl Thomas III` or `Billy Bob Thornton Sr.` or `Smith, John`? Name cleansing is complicated.

Comment: @Larnu    question updated

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: @Larnu  when charindex returns 0 , i want to include this condition in above so that it does not give error when blank values is encountered

Comment: We really need more than one sample here. What happened to the column `LastName` in your expected results? Also, does your column `contact_name` really contain line breaks? Supply the sample data as DDL and DML statements, and the expected results as tabular formatted `text`.

Comment: Lastname query is working fine and contact_name contains line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

I find that the simplest way to fix this in SQL Server is to append the character you are looking for in the `charindex()` calls.

Instead of:

```
CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Contact_name))
```

Ues:

```
CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Contact_name) + ' ')
```

Comment: i have used CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Contact_name) + ' ') but it is giving same error

Comment: @rajiv . . . for both `CHARINDEX()` calls?

Answer (score 0):

using rtrim i was able to resolve my issue.

```
update sports
set firstname= LEFT(Contact_name, LEN(Contact_name) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(rtrim(Contact_name))))
```

Thanks @ Gordon for your time